# Add a user in a sharepoint group using powerhsell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, groups, spgroup

I would like to know how to add a SharePoint user in a SharePoint group.
This snippet is working for some accounts and doesn't not for some others.
Why ?

**Note:** When I using the SharePoint UI to add the not working accounts within the desired group, it's working. I just have to use the *Check the names* button to find the corresponding account.

```
$webUrl = "http://www.sitecollection/site";
$groupeName = "Groupe name";
$compte = "DOMAIN\account"; 
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl;    
$user = Get-SPUser -web $web.url -Identity $compte -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;               
$group = $web.SiteGroups[$groupeName];  
$web.EnsureUser($user);
$group.AddUser($user);
```

***Exception calling "AddUser" with "1" argument(s): user doesn't exist or is not unique.***

Comment: You don't need Get-SPUser. Try: $user = $web.EnsureUser($compte)

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's still not working. With or without *Get-SPUser*.

Answer (score 1):

The user record will create into `User Information List` on the first-time login. When you execute the statement `Get-SPUser` if a user is not found it returns `null`. And you are executing `$web.EnsureUser($user)` on null value.

You can change your code as follows.

```
....
....
$user = $web.EnsureUser($compte); //$compte is user login name
$group = $web.SiteGroups[$groupeName];
$group.AddUser($user);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying and for the advice. Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything :'(

Comment: Can you print user details after EnsureUser statement to make sure this returns user object

Comment: I printed it and it displays 2 columns **UserLogin** and **Displayname** with the expected value inside.

Comment: If it is returning expected value then it should add to the group. I will verify this again on my server.